# focus view of google sheets with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a `google sheets` with a calendar where every column from `C4:CA4` are dates.

I have also freezed columns `A` and `B`

I would like to adjust the view of the spreadsheet the the most recent date.

In cell `A2` I have created a cell with `Today()` to get the current date.

I would like to find the `Today()` in the range `C4:CA4` and make that column the left most column (first thing the user views)

I have done:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  const curr_day = sh.getRange("A2");
  const curr_day_val = curr_day.getValue();

  const dates = sh.getRange("C4:CA4").getValues().flat(); 
  const checkDif = dates.map(d=>curr_day_val - d).filter(v=>v>0);
  const minIndex = checkDif.indexOf(Math.min(...checkDif))+2;

  const targetCell = sh.getRange(curr_day.getRow()+4, curr_day.getColumn() + minIndex);

  sh.setActiveRange(targetCell);
}
```

But this code is not able to do it.

How can I change it to make the column where `Today()` exists the left-most column in the freeze panel?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to activate the column of today's date.
- You want to show the searched column to just the right side of the frozen columns "A" and "B".

In this case, how about the following modification?

In order to show the column to the right side of the frozen columns "A" and "B", the methods of `hideColumns` and `showColumns`. By this, I thought that your goal might be able to be achieved. I thought that this process might be an important point for achieving your expected result.

#### Modified script:

In this case, when you open the Spreadsheet, this script is automatically run by the simple trigger of OnOpen.

```js
function onOpen() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  const curr_day = sh.getRange("A2");
  const curr_day_val = curr_day.getValue();
  const dates = sh.getRange("C4:CA4").getValues().flat();
  const checkDif = dates.map(d => curr_day_val - d).filter(v => v > 0);
  const minIndex = checkDif.indexOf(Math.min(...checkDif)) + 3;
  if (minIndex > 2) {
    sh.hideColumns(3, minIndex - 2);
    sh.showColumns(1, sh.getLastColumn());
  }
  const targetCell = sh.getRange(curr_day.getRow() + 4, curr_day.getColumn() + minIndex);
  sh.setActiveRange(targetCell);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this modified script, the row of the active cell is from `curr_day.getRow()+4` of your showing script. Please be careful about this.
- For example, when the maximum column of your Spreadsheet is column "CA" and the value of cell "A2" is column, the column "CA" cannot be shown on just the right side of the frozen columns "A" and "B". Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideColumns(Integer,Integer))
- [showColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showcolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns)
- [Focusing Selected Cell to Top Left on Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/focusing-selected-cell-to-top-left-on-google-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script-602f91a1bdec)

  - I published a general sample script for implementing both rows and columns to this situation as a report.